# Vue - How to render HTML in vue components

Tags: vue.js, render, directive

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
{{ span('Hello') }}
```

And what desired output should be is:

```
<span>
   Hello
</span>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Obviously possible, but can you share what you have tried yet?

Comment: You should use JSX to display for this purpose! Follow here https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-jsx-with-vue-and-why-you-should-care

Comment: @SatyamPathak well, what I really want to accomplish is that, when a certain configuration is turned on, the method needs to add a 'span' or a 'button' around it so I can click on it.

Comment: That looks like something you fundamentally avoid doing! People need to understand your method, and the overall result obscures what's going on.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Look at the below snippet -

Note - You can't render `html` inside `{{  }}` because it get added to text node of the element. To render it as an html you need to use `v-html` and have your function which return `element` wrapping your text

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    foo: 'asdasd'
  },
  methods: {
   span(text) {
    return `<span> ${text} </span>`
   }
  }
})
```

```css
span {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <h1> 
    Render whatever you want
  </h1>
  <div v-html="span('Hello world')" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could not render HTML in the brackets.
Used your solution to continue

Answer (score 4):

For Vue3 it is `v-html="htmlContent"`

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @theTinMan. I will keep this in mind next time and I will also edit the above answer :)

Answer (score 3):

`<span>{{Hello}}</span>`

If you need dynamic HTML tag
`<tag :is="tag">{{Hello}}</tag>`

```
Vue.component('tag', {
  props:{
     is:{type:String, required:true}
  },
  render(h){
    return h(this.tag, this.$slots.default)
  }
})
new Vue({
    el:'#vue',
    data(){
    return {
        tag:'h1'
    }
  }
})
```